# Not understanding mathematical solution to implementation task

Tags: c++, algorithm

The problem sounds like that:

> Kevin has N friends and one building. He wants to organize a
>   party in that building and he invites exacly *1 friend / day*. Kevin
>   unfortunately has grumpy neighbors which aren't too happy with the
>   noise that Kevin's party does. For that, Kevin wants to minimize the
>   noise level of his party. (the noise level is equal to the number of
>   friends in the building) In order to do that, after some day he can
>   clear the building by asking his friends to leave (**he can do that K times, for K different days**). (*ex*: he clears the
>   building after day 2 so at day 3 when he invites another friend, for
>   day 3 the noise level will be 1 because the past day he cleared the
>   building; if he didn't clear the building at day 2, the noise level
>   for day 3 will have been 3 (1 from day 2, 1 from day 1 and the new invited friend) and the total noise level for day 1, 2 and 3 would have been 1+2+3=6).

For better understanding the task:

**Input:**

```
5 2 (N, K)
```

**Output:**

```
7
```

**Explanation:**

In the input example, N friends will be invited at the party, in the following order:

```
1 (day 1)                                                       1 (day 1)
1 (day 2)    so in the building for each day will be present    2 (day 2)
1 (day 3)   ------------------------------------------------->  3 (day 3)
1 (day 4)          (without clearing the building)              4 (day 4)
1 (day 5)                                                       5 (day 5)
                                                             -----(+)
                                                               15
```

So, clearing the building 0 times (**K=0**), the noise level will be 15.

Clearing the building 1 time (**K=1**), the sum will be:

```
(0 times)
    1                                              1
 __ 2 __     clearing the building after day 2     2
    3       ----------------------------------->   1
    4                                              2
    5                                              3
                                                 ----(+)
                                                   9
```

At this case (K=1), another solution could be to clear after day 3, same sum.

Clearing 2 times (**K=2**):

```
(0 times)
    1                                                  1
 __ 2 __     clearing the building after day 2 & 3     2
 __ 3 __    -------------------------------------->    1
    4                                                  1
    5                                                  2
                                                     ----(+)
                                                       7
```

---

I have the solution but I don't understand it!

I tried, took some other cases but still nothing, maybe you guys can explain me why the solution is the way it is.

This is how sum(N, K) is calculated:

> sum(N, K) = minimum noise level clearing the building K times (K>=0)

**C++ code:**

```
int sum(int n)
 {
    return n * (n + 1) / 2;
 }

int solve(int n, int k)
{
    int p = k + 1;
    int mp = n/p;
    int bp = (n+p-1)/p;
    int nmaj = n%p;
    int nmic = p-nmaj;

    return nmic * sum(mp) + nmaj*sum(bp);
}
```

What is the purpose of each variable?

What does `nmic * sum(mp)` and `nmaj*sum(bp)` computes?

**!!!!**

For the example above (at the beginning - N=5, K=2), I debugged the code and wrote for `N=5, K=0..2` the value for each variable, hoping to get the idea but no succes. I am going to post them for you, maybe you'll get the idea and then explain to me (I am a novice in algorithmic problems).

Here is it:

**[variable values for each case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WVM8.png)**

I repeat, I tried for some hours to understand but no succes. And it's not a homework. Thank you!

Comment: **down vote**? At least you could tell me why.

Comment: There's a lot of information here that isn't relevant to the immediate problem. Plus you've supplied a link which is never satisfactory since they tend to decay. A question that is beautifully formatted such as this will not necessarily attract upvotes.

Comment: Okay @Bathsheba, I understand. I just hope that someone will help me :)

Comment: The easiest way to program a solution for this would be to simply try out all combinations of when to clear the house. The solution you posted apparantly performs some clever mathematical trick that avoids having to try out all possibilities. Did you try to just program a simple, exhaustive solution?

Comment: No @wvdz, backtracking doesn't help me at all at what I want to do further with this problem.

Comment: what does this have to do with backtracking?

Comment: In any case, if you want to analyze this solution, just write down the solve() function as a mathematical formula and try to reason why it is correct. If you can't figure that out, I suggest asking on http://math.stackexchange.com/ instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code goes like this:

```
int p = k+1;
```

`p` is the number of "parts" in which you divide the days (Ex: Day1 + Day2 = part1, Day 3 + Day4 = part2, Day 5 = part3)

```
int mp = n/p;
```

`mp` is the amount of days the minor part has, in the example is 1 (Day5). It's calculated as the floor of the number of days over the number of parts.

```
int bp = (n+p-1)/p;
```

`bp` is the amount of days in the bigger part, in the example is 2 (Day1 + Day2 or Day3 + Day4). I don't really get the exact math behind but that's what it calculates

```
int nmaj = n%p;
int nmic = p-nmaj;
```

`nmaj` is the number of major parts, in the example is 2 (Day1 + Day2 and Day3 + Day4), the `nmic` is the number of minor parts (1 for Day5).

```
nmic * sum(mp) + nmaj*sum(bp);
```

This just returns the number of minor parts * the accumulated value in minor parts + number of major parts * the accumulated value in major parts

The `sum` function is just the formula for arithmetic series (Or summation of arithmetic progressions) for the special case of initial element = 1